# convert apklib to jar

Tags: java, android, maven

How do i go about converting my apklib to a jar? I'd like to open source and allow non-maven developers to use my code. My code doesn't use anything maven specific. It doesn't use in xml files or images, just java. I tried changing the packaging to jar and that failed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.oss</groupId>
        <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
        <version>5</version>
    </parent>

    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <groupId>com.programmingarehard</groupId>
    <artifactId>freshorm</artifactId>
    <packaging>apklib</packaging>
    <name>FreshORM</name>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <binary.prefix>fresh</binary.prefix>
        <android.version>4.1.1.4</android.version>
        <android.platform>16</android.platform>
        <android.support.version>r7</android.support.version>

        <!-- Test Dependencies -->
        <junit.version>4.10</junit.version>
        <fest.version>2.0M7</fest.version>
        <robolectric.version>2.0-alpha-1</robolectric.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>${android.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
            <artifactId>fest-assert-core</artifactId>
            <version>${fest.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.robolectric</groupId>
            <artifactId>robolectric</artifactId>
            <version>${robolectric.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <classifier>no_aop</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <!-- platform or api level (api level 4 = platform 1.6)-->
                        <path>/Users/davidadams/Documents/android-sdk-macosx</path>
                        <platform>16</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/Test*.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: May be you could distribute the source as an android library project?

Answer (score 0):

> I tried changing the packaging to jar and that failed.

I think you'd be better of fixing the problem cause the JAR packaging to fail instead of trying to convert from Java bytecodes to Davlik and back again.

If you mentioned *how* it failed, we might be able to help you with that ...

---

Here's a thought.  Create a second Maven project / POM with packaging "jar" and move all of the (reusable) Java code there.  Then make that project a dependency of this one.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/gitskarios/Gitskarios-core

Maybe this will help you, when I use the command `mvn clean install`, it will create `apklib` and `jar` at the same time, and put them into my local repo: `~/m2/path/to/myprojectid`